# Kubernates for windows container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have a asp.net core application whose docker image is build in windows containers. I want to integrate this image with kubernetes using minikube.

I was performing the below steps which didn't worked.

1. minikube config set driver hyperv
2. minikube delete
3. minikube start (creates a default vm for linux os)
4. minikube start --hyperv-virtual-switch "External" --iso-url=D:\windows-amd64.iso

Performing the step 4, I expect the vm to be updated and it's OS to be changed to windows. However, the vm doesn't get updated and the os remains the same as linux.

Please provide a solution to it.

Also I have tried driver as docker but minikube supports linux images. So is there any other way to achieve the deployment using windows image?

Answer (score 0):

The iso is not a "live distribution", it's not even an unattended installation, and out of the box, there is no docker support installed.

On top of that, minikube supports only Linux containers - on a Windows host via a VM - but only Linux guests after all.

You'll have to use a more complete Kubernetes implementation for this job, e.g. setting up cubectl straight on the host will usually work.

Just beware of the finer details of Windows containers: You can't mix Windows versions between host and container! Both have to be Windows Server with the same major version.